# If an dataflow sdk option is annotated with "Experimental" or "Hidden", am I safe to use it?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Some options are annotated with *Experimental* or *Hidden* in the SDK, can I use them safely? What can I expect? Examples are:

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/DataflowPipelineOptions.html#getServiceAccount--

```
@Hidden
@Experimental
String getServiceAccount() // corresponding to --serviceAccount
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically,

*@Hidden* means that the option is just hidden from --help.

*@Experimental* means there's no compatibility commitment to the option (or not supported). Note that the presence of the annotation implies nothing about the quality or performance of the API in question, only the fact that it is not "API-frozen."

Per https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/annotations/Experimental

> It is generally safe for applications to depend on experimental APIs, at the cost of some extra work during upgrades. However, it is generally inadvisable for libraries (which get included on users' class paths, outside the library developers' control) to do so.